# Automation Tools for Desktop Application that runs in the Cloud

Tags: automated-testing, desktop-application

Are there any tools that we can use to automate testing for a desktop application that runs in the cloud?

Basically the application is running in the cloud, and we can initiate that application (server-side application) by accessing the cloud through web-browser.

Comment: What solutions have you looked at?  Why don't browserstack or sourcelabs provide what you need?